# This query won't work unless I format it on an SQL formatter, but it looks the same

Tags: mysql, sql

the database architecture is a basic one.
Even though the query looks the same, it won't work unless I format it using an online query formatter.
Output before using sql formatter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LnzU.jpg 
Output after using the sql formatter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUUGM.jpg

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    COUNT(rating) AS 'COUNT',
    IFNULL(MIN(rating), 0) AS 'MIN',
    IFNULL(MAX(rating), 0) AS 'MAX',
    IFNULL(AVG(rating), 0) AS 'AVG',
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(rating) >= 1 THEN 'ACTIVE'
        ELSE 'INACTIVE'
    END AS 'STATUS'
FROM reviewers
LEFT JOIN reviews
    ON reviewers.id = reviews.reviewer_id
GROUP BY reviewers.id;
```

Comment: Why are you putting your column aliases in single quotes?  Even if that works, I don't think you should be doing it.

Comment: This query is invalid because you are only grouping by `reviewers.id`, but are selecting many other non aggregate columns.  Could it be that the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` modes are different in the two places you are running this query?

Comment: I understand that single quotes is bad practice and thanks for the advice. But the query works after I paste it into a mysql formatter(I don't modify anything). That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Can you answer my second comment?

Comment: No, the modes are not different.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query - I cut and pasted it from the question into `PHPMyAdmin` and it worked fine (although it did complain that there should have been `()`'s around the `CASE`). I suspect you have a non-printable character in the original text. Try cutting and pasting the query back out of this question and see if you still have the same problem.